# How do I make Areas, Work Items, and Fields unique to a project so that other projects can't see them in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, project, agile

The way we have Azure DevOps set up currently is that there are a bunch of projects for different departments, and everyone is bound to the same settings for work items and fields. This is just a remnant of the early days when DevOps was setup, I'm currently looking into separating my departments single project from all the others.

Whenever an update needs to be made on work items and their fields, this change happens across all projects, so when one department wants to make a field within lets say tasks mandatory, it'll be mandatory for all other departments to fill in that field too. This has caused a lot of issues with how DevOps is structured and organised within my department. I'm trying to figure out how we can keep all the work items and fields as is for other projects, but within my project have it so we can create/delete/modify work items without it affecting the other projects. The same would go for creating Areas, essentially we want to be completely separate from any other project.

Is there any way to do this?

I've tried looking into the work item settings within Azure DevOps to see if I can figure out how to separate our project from the rest. I've also looked at documentation to try and see if it's mentioned anywhere but can't seem to find anything related to what I want to do.

Comment: 1.Normally, WITs are separated in each projects, why the changes on WITs in your project would affect another one project in your org, and how does this workflow work?

2.If for WITs in one project, by setting new Area Path can achieve the distribution management on WITs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-an-area-path

Comment: @RoyWang-MSFT oooh wait I see how it works now, so under Boards -> 'Process' is where work items are created? We currently have 17 projects against a single process, this must be why all our projects share the same work items and fields correct?

If I create a new process and re-create only the necessary work items and fields, then put our project onto that new process, this should allow us to separate away from all the unnecessary work items already created in this older process?

Comment: If this is all correct my only real question would be what would happen to a work item, lets just say for example the bug work item, if there are tickets using that work item but it now no longer exists? Will it change them in anyway?

Or what about if bug still exists but the fields have completely changed, will the old bug tickets also be changed to reflect this?

I'd love to test this myself but sadly I don't have the permission to do so yet within my company.